# Text extraction from .docx file

Tags: c#, text, ms-word, nlp, docx

I'm aware of libraries that are capable of this, but they aren't useful to me given constraints in their licensing structure or the cost associated.  I'd like to extract the text contents from a Word file (docx) and am close, but encountering a small issue.

First, I extract to a temporary directory:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(_Filename))
{
    archive.ExtractToDirectory(_TempDirectory);
}
```

Then load the `XmlDocument` and find the body:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(_TempDirectory + "word/document.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("w:body");
```

And then iterate over each of the nodes and joining the extracted text using a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    sb.Append(ExtractAllText(node));
}

return sb.ToString();
```

The contents of `ExtractAllText` is:

```
private string ExtractAllText(XmlNode node)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text: node name " + node.Name + " " + node.Value);

        sb.Append(node.InnerText);

        if (node.Attributes != null)
        {
            foreach (var attr in node.Attributes) Console.WriteLine(attr.ToString());
            // displays nothing for any node!
        }
    }

    if (node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode curr in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            sb.Append(ExtractAllText(curr));
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The problem I'm facing is this: sometimes strings are split into two separate nodes and sometimes they aren't.  Further, the XML gives indication that whitespace should be preserved (e.g. `<w:t xml:space="preserve">, </w:t>` but I cannot seem to access this via `node.Attributes`.   I'm assuming that accessing this attribute (`xml:space` and `preserve`) would allow me to understand whether or not to append whitespace to the `StringBuilder` before or after the text of that particular node.

This results in a Word doc that looks like this:
[image: word doc]

Resulting in a string like this:
`My Name123 Vine Street, San Jose CA 95128 USA |(408) 555-1212my@email.com | www.mysite.com | linkedinobjectiveThis is my resume objective section!`

Note how "My Name" and "123 Vine Street" are joined, and other similar examples exist.

Any input or advice would be much appreciated!

Edit:
Also tried with `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` and encountered similar results:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_Filename, false))
{
    body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    return body.InnerText;
}
```

Shows:

```
My Name123 Vine Street, San Jose CA 95128 USA  |  (408) 555-1212my@email.com | www.mysite.com | linkedinobjectiveThis is my resume objective section!
```

Edit 2: another attempt with `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` produced again the same problem:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(_Filename, false))
{
    foreach (OpenXmlElement element in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements())
    {
        if (element is Table)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table: " + element.InnerText);
        }
        else if (element is Paragraph)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Paragraph: " + element.InnerText);
        }
        else if (element is Run)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Run: " + element.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
Table: My Name123 Vine Street, San Jose CA 95128 USA  |  (408) 555-1212my@email.com | www.mysite.com | linkedin
Paragraph: objective
Paragraph: This is my resume objective section!
```

Comment: Use NuGet package [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK). You may consider using the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5) as well.

Comment: Having a resume in that format isn't recommended because resumes these days are scanned in and the data is extracted from them. While using vertical and horizontal lines may look appealing, they don't work well with resume websites or with the software that employers use to extract data from the scanned in resumes which means that such a resume may end up in the trash can rather than in a database somewhere.

Comment: It's just a sample document and not indicative of the entirety of documents from which I wish to extract text.  But duly noted should I ever upload a resume :)

Comment: Results have same issue as what I'm showing above, see above edit.

Comment: If you open the Word document with the _Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool_ and click _Reflect Code_, then you'll be able to see how the document is represented.